# What partitions are safe to delete on windows 8 and ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows, 15.04

What partitions are safe to delete if your planning to reinstall ubuntu and make it your only os by wiping your hard drive

Edit: I also have ubuntu install at the moment what im trying to do is downgrade to 14.04 but I was told I need to delete partitions so hence question above.

Comment: If you do not need Windows and do not plan to recover it, you can delete all partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete any partition marked as NTFS since those are all Windows.

But I would suggest to always keep the recovery partition if present. You never know if you want to sell that machine. It will be clearly marked as a "recovery" partition.

If you want Ubuntu as a single OS you can use the installer to remove partitions. There is no need to do this from inside the current Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: Sometimes there are other partitions required for recovery. Not the only the "recovery" one. It is vendor dependent.